# Gameplay Crashes From ipa file but runs fine from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, crash, ipa

It is somewhat an awkward situation right now.

When I run my project directly from Xcode to my device it runs perfect without any crashs. But when I create an ipa file of that project and install that ipa into my device by using iTunes, only for the first time when I launch my gameplay screen it crashes, later on when I starts my gameplay it runs fine.

Remember, my gameplay starts after the user navigates 2 initial screens which works pretty fine in either conditions. (i.e running from Xcode or from ipa file).

What I dont understand is that if the problem is in my init method of the gameplay class why it does not crashes when I run it directly from Xcode. Is there any code compression or different mechanism of code compilation when running as an ipa or from Xcode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the crash log from your device ? You can probably get some pointers from it.

Comment: hi..i have same problem with my code...its work fine when running from code...and got crashed when running after making ipa...whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adig said, get crashlog from device, then symbolicate it. You will see call stack and the line, that caused crash. All differences between release, debug, ad hoc, etc. build configuration you can setup in your project.

Comment: Actually there was a memory leak at the main thread of the program. I was using CCTransition with a delay among screens and when I removed it from my code the ipa worked fine. But I don't understand why the .ipa file has different behavior than the file which we run directly from Xcode. Some pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same scenario, the ipa file was crashing after two initial screens. The crashlog did give the line of crash in the code. Debugging the code did not solve the purpose.

But I solved the issue by checking the Archive settings in the Edit Scheme section. 
My Build was in Debug mode and the Archive setting was Release, I changed the Archive's build configuration to Debug and created an ipa and the crash was resolved.

Hope this helps someone save productive time. Thanks.

Comment: I had uploaded the Release build on the AppStore and as obvious my live game started crashing too.

I then just deleted the existing _Release_ configurations in the Project settings and duplicated the _Debug_ configurations and renamed it Release and updated required settings.

This got me working atlast after spending months on this prob. There seemed to be a problem with the configuration