# App Crashes From ipa file but runs fine from Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, ipa

When I run my project directly from Xcode to my device it runs perfect without any crashes. But when I create an ipa file of that project and install that ipa into my device by using iTunes, when i click on the login button it crashes,later so many tries for logins after that it works fine.

if refer this issue on internet by it doesn't help for me. this are the links i refer

[App works fine with developer build with xcode. But crashes when run using ipa file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359129/app-works-fine-with-developer-build-with-xcode-but-crashes-when-run-using-ipa-f)

[Gameplay Crashes From ipa file but runs fine from Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477809/gameplay-crashes-from-ipa-file-but-runs-fine-from-xcode)

i don't understand what is the actual problem with the achieve ipa file. 
why it does not crashes when I run it directly from Xcode. Is there any code compression or different mechanism of code compilation when running as an ipa or from Xcode.

Any help would be appreciated.

CrashLog

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib      0x00000001010b25dc 0x100f74000 + 1304028
1   AppName                 0x00000001001030c4 0x1000bc000 + 291012
2   Appname                 0x00000001001062cc 0x1000bc000 + 303820
3   Alamofire               0x00000001004c9c9c 0x10047c000 + 318620
4   Alamofire               0x00000001004c899c 0x10047c000 + 313756
5   Alamofire               0x0000000100486d08 0x10047c000 + 44296
6   libdispatch.dylib       0x000000018571e1fc 0x18571d000 + 4604
7   libdispatch.dylib       0x000000018571e1bc 0x18571d000 + 4540
8   libdispatch.dylib       0x0000000185722d68 0x18571d000 + 23912
9   CoreFoundation          0x0000000186842810 0x186765000 + 907280
10  CoreFoundation          0x00000001868403fc 0x186765000 + 898044
11  CoreFoundation          0x000000018676e2b8 0x186765000 + 37560
12  GraphicsServices        0x0000000188222198 0x188216000 + 49560
13  UIKit                   0x000000018c7b57fc 0x18c73b000 + 501756
14  UIKit                   0x000000018c7b0534 0x18c73b000 + 480564
15  AppName                 0x0000000100139e4c 0x1000bc000 + 515660
16  libdyld.dylib           0x00000001857515b8 0x18574d000 + 17848

Thread 1:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000185863a88 0x185844000 + 129672
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185927344 0x185926000 + 4932
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185926d8c 0x185926000 + 3468

Thread 2:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000185863a88 0x185844000 + 129672
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185927160 0x185926000 + 4448
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185926d8c 0x185926000 + 3468

 Thread 3:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib   0x0000000185863a88 0x185844000 + 129672
 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185927344 0x185926000 + 4932
 2   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185926d8c 0x185926000 + 3468

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x0000000185863a88 0x185844000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000185927344 0x185926000 + 4932
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib     0x0000000185926d8c 0x185926000 + 3468

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib      0x0000000185845188 0x185844000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib      0x0000000185844ff8 0x185844000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation            0x00000001868425d0 0x186765000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation            0x00000001868401ec 0x186765000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation            0x000000018676e2b8 0x186765000 + 37560
5   Foundation                0x00000001872ab26c 0x18729f000 + 49772
6   Foundation                0x00000001872cbdd0 0x18729f000 + 183760
7   UIKit                   0x000000018d129c38 0x18c73b000 + 10415160
8  Foundation                0x00000001873a8e68 0x18729f000 + 1089128
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185929850 0x185926000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185929760 0x185926000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185926d94 0x185926000 + 3476

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib   0x0000000185862e1c 0x185844000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00000001859289c0 0x185926000 + 10688
2   libc++.1.dylib           0x00000001852513ec 0x18524a000 + 29676
3   JavaScriptCore           0x000000018b0725d0 0x18a799000 + 9278928
4   JavaScriptCore           0x000000018b072544 0x18a799000 + 9278788
5   JavaScriptCore           0x000000018b072424 0x18a799000 + 9278500
6   JavaScriptCore           0x000000018b0726d4 0x18a799000 + 9279188
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185929850 0x185926000 + 14416
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185929760 0x185926000 + 14176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185926d94 0x185926000 + 3476

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x0000000185845188 0x185844000 + 4488
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x0000000185844ff8 0x185844000 + 4088
2   CoreFoundation            0x00000001868425d0 0x186765000 + 906704
3   CoreFoundation            0x00000001868401ec 0x186765000 + 897516
4   CoreFoundation            0x000000018676e2b8 0x186765000 + 37560
5   CFNetwork                 0x0000000186f73a70 0x186e94000 + 916080
6   Foundation               0x00000001873a8e68 0x18729f000 + 1089128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x0000000185929850 0x185926000 + 14416
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185929760 0x185926000 + 14176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x0000000185926d94 0x185926000 + 3476

Thread 8 name:  JIT Worklist Worker Thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib  0x0000000185862e1c 0x185844000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00000001859289c0 0x185926000 + 10688
2   libc++.1.dylib          0x00000001852513ec 0x18524a000 + 29676
3   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018b05ad64 0x18a799000 + 9182564
4   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018ae32a5c 0x18a799000 + 6920796
5   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018ae32eac 0x18a799000 + 6921900
6   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018a7a300c 0x18a799000 + 40972
7   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018a7a2f1c 0x18a799000 + 40732
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000185929850 0x185926000 + 14416
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000185929760 0x185926000 + 14176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x0000000185926d94 0x185926000 + 3476

 Thread 9 name:  WTF Parallel Helper Thread
 Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x0000000185862e1c 0x185844000 + 126492
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00000001859289c0 0x185926000 + 10688
2   libc++.1.dylib            0x00000001852513ec 0x18524a000 + 29676
3   JavaScriptCore           0x000000018b05ad64 0x18a799000 + 9182564
4   JavaScriptCore           0x000000018b05a2e8 0x18a799000 + 9179880
5   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018b05a088 0x18a799000 + 9179272
6   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018a7a300c 0x18a799000 + 40972
7   JavaScriptCore          0x000000018a7a2f1c 0x18a799000 + 40732
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185929850 0x185926000 + 14416
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185929760 0x185926000 + 14176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185926d94 0x185926000 + 3476

 Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
 Thread 10:
 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x0000000185845188 0x185844000 + 4488
 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib    0x0000000185844ff8 0x185844000 + 4088
 2   CoreFoundation           0x00000001868425d0 0x186765000 + 906704
 3   CoreFoundation           0x00000001868401ec 0x186765000 + 897516
 4   CoreFoundation           0x000000018676e2b8 0x186765000 + 37560
 5   CoreFoundation           0x00000001867bbb44 0x186765000 + 355140
 6   CoreMotion               0x000000018d631120 0x18d5c3000 + 450848
 7   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185929850 0x185926000 + 14416
 8   libsystem_pthread.dyli   0x0000000185929760 0x185926000 + 14176
 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000185926d94 0x185926000 + 3476

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
 x0: 0x0000000101524380   x1: 0x00000001702f4d00  
    x2:0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x00000001858a922c
x4: 0x0000000000000014   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 
    0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000600
x8: 0x00000001702f4900   x9: 0x00000001702f4900  x10:    
    0x0000000000000001  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
x12: 0x0000010000000100  x13: 0x206e6120676e6970  x14: 
    0x6c616e6f6974704f  x15: 0x000a65756c617620
x16: 0x00000001858996b0  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 
    0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000170442eb0
x20: 0x0000000170e67400  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 
    0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000014
x24: 0x00000001ac178d20  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 
    0xffffffffffffffff  x27: 0x0000000170e67400
x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016fd415b0   lr: 
    0x00000001010b25dc
sp: 0x000000016fd415a0   pc: 0x00000001010b25dc cpsr: 0x20000000
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe if it is some special issue, it will good to look at system log.

Comment: Sometimes you need to check the compilation flags you're using. Some flags may cause crashes on devices.

Comment: @SamuelTulach i check the crash log : Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed: this is the crashed part i have seen.

Comment: @Zico actually when the app launch their is login page. when i enter the username ,password and then click login button it crushes. but in xcode it doesnt crush it works fine. the problem only showing in ipa file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should look at the crashing logs.

1. connect you device to you Mac
2. in Xcode, press cmd+shift+2.
3. find you device, and press the log button
4. wait a while. then you can see all crashing logs.
5. find the ones with your app's name. If you don't understand it, post it  here.

Comment: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:

Comment: @user5747934 You should paste all of the log.

Comment: i added the crash log. please take a look through that

Comment: @user5747934 I suggest you comment some lines and rebuild your app, repeat this until you can locate the lines that causes this issue.

Comment: Json section got error i think. now i am doing with your suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

I have also gone through same issue

You have to edit your scheme

Archive --> Build Configuration --> set this to Debug
Try to archive and test your IPA now.. it should work fine.

Comment: i have done this before. :) we can give this ipa file to appstore with the scheme Achieve as debug mode?.

Comment: Yes we can.. I have submitted the same file with Debug mode. It got approved also @Sreejiths

Comment: you are a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you build your app with different build configurations basically using the `Debug` configuration when you run it from Xcode and the `Release` configuration for deployment as ipa. We had a similar issue with unexplainable bugs in the release configuration and figured out that the Swift Optimization caused the problem. For now we switched from `Fast, Whole Module Optimization` to `Fast, Single-File Optimization` for the release builds until we can narrow down the problem.

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: i have tried this method but i don't find this working. In this app i am using Alamofire is their any problem with that?.

Comment: @Sreejiths did you find solution for it ..?

Comment: My debug build works fine but my release version gives crash Trying to know the problem.

Comment: this has worked for me. I had a SwiftUI app that was crashing because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors that were almost impossible to debug. Unfortunately, the options in the newer versions of xcode are different so I chose "None [-Onone]" optimisation for release to make it work